# Why go vet report uint(0) might be too small for shift of 63?

Tags: go

[The Go Programming Language book](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/), exercise 6.5, the author told us using this expression:

```
32 << (^uint(0) >> 63)
```

to check whether the platform is 32-bit or 64-bit.

The expression is quite clear, and we can check the result with a simple code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(32 << (^uint(0) >> 63))
}
```

The code print `0` on 32-bit platform and `64` on 64-bit platform.

However, using `go vet` with the file, I receive the warning:

```
$ go vet ex6-5.go 
ex6-5.go:6: ^uint(0) might be too small for shift of 63
exit status 1
```

Why does `go vet` show me that warnings? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `uint` is not a fixed bitwise length type, it could be as short as a 32 bits, so not sufficient for you to right shift by 63.

This is also the reason why you could use this expression to test the platform, since `uint` would take the most efficient `int` type on the platform.

If on 32-bit platform, `uint` is 32-bit length, and thus the right shift would give `0`, which causes `32` in the end as the result of `32 << 0`. But on 64-bit platform, `uint` gives 64-bit, and thus right shift 63 bits would give you `1` instead of `0`, which results in `64` at the end since `32 << 1` gives `64`.

Take a look at the source code of vet:

```
71      case types.Int, types.Uint, types.Uintptr:
72          // These types may be as small as 32 bits, but no smaller.
73          size = 32
74          msg = "might be "
...
78      if amt >= size {
79          ident := f.gofmt(x)
80          f.Badf(node.Pos(), "%s %stoo small for shift of %d", ident, msg, amt)
81      }
```

That is to say, as long as you are using uint and right shift by 63 bits, with `go vet` checking `shift`, there's no way to escape the check. You could try to skip that by providing the flag to check:

```
go tool vet -shift=false yourfile.go
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does go vet show me that warnings? How can I prevent it?

nevets's answer proposed:

> You could try to skip that by providing the flag to check:

```
go tool vet -shift=false yourfile.go
```

But: You should not use `go tool vet`. Only `go vet`. Or in this case, only because you need to pass a flag.

However, starting go 1.10 (Q1 2018), that will change: see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/qfa3mHN4ZPA/X2UzjNV1BAAJ):

> **Do not use "`go tool vet`", which is essentially only useful to people working on `vet`** (just like you don't typically run "`go tool compile`").
>
> Previously you needed to use "`go tool vet`" if you wanted control over vet flags, but **"`go vet`" now accepts all the flags that "`go tool vet`" does**. (See "`go help vet`".)

So `go vet -shift=false yourfile.go` should be enough.